# Входящие параметры метода Dictionary

Tags: c#, коллекции

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда метод принимает входящие параметры коллекции словаря, подскажите пожалуйста, как осуществить передачу параметров в метод.

```
    public bool SendMail(Dictionary<string, string> message)
    {
        try
        {
            var from = "MailAdress";
            var pass = "password";

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, pass);
            client.EnableSsl = true;


            var mail = new MailMessage(from, message["Delivery"]);
            mail.Subject = message["Subject"];
            mail.Body = message["Body"];
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            client.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Каких параметров? В какой метод? Что это за кусок кода и где в нем проблема? Мне кажется, вопрос требует уточнения

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Что именно не получается? Почему вы используете словарь таким образом? Здесь больше подошел бы обычный класс.

Comment: @tym32167 Нужно использовать метод, который прикрепил. Не могу использовать его через main метод

Comment: Какая ошибка у вас возникает? Или в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам непонятно, как составлять message?

```
var message = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Subject", "Мой заголовок письма"},
    {"Body", "Содержимое письма"},
    {"Delivery", "Email@Addr.ru"},
};
SendMail(message);
```

Или как вариант:

```
var message = new Dictionary<string, string>();
message.Add("Subject", "Мой заголовок письма");
message.Add("Body", "Содержимое письма");
message.Add("Delivery", "Email@Addr.ru");
SendMail(message);
```

Легко гуглится по словам c# initialize dictionary, например [Proper way to initialize a C# dictionary with values already in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17047602/5752652)

Но вообще, лучше не использовать в подобных случаях словарь, так как код будет достаточно хрупким и из-за небольших опечаток может сломаться.

Давайте лучше переделаем на класс:

```
public class MailMessageParams
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string HtmlBody { get; set; }

    public MailAddress To { get; set; }
}
```

Переделаем ваш метод:

```
public bool SendMail(MailMessageParams message)
{
    try
    {
        var from = "MailAdress";
        var pass = "password";

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, pass);
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        var mail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(from), message.To);
        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.HtmlBody;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        client.Send(mail);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Вызов:

```
var message = new MailMessageParams
{
    Subject = "Мой заголовок письма",
    HtmlBody = "Html содержимое письма",
    To = new MailAddress("Email@Addr.ru"),
};
SendMail(message);
```

Comment: этот код споткнется тут `message["Delivery"]`

Comment: Спасибо, нашел кусок кода, с которым нужно разобратся, теперь ломаю голову. Спасибо за ответ и за ссылку, где можно найти по вопросу информацию.

Comment: @Rifter Наверное, вам нужно сначала почитать структуры данных. Вот например [ссылка про Dictionary](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.9.php) на русском.

Comment: @AK, не надо поощрять использование словаря там, где он не нужен. Автору нужно использовать классы!

Comment: @АндрейNOP Замечание хорошее, но боюсь, что на текущем уровне он пока с опаской будет следовать подобным советам. Сейчас добавлю.

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо за приложенный вариант без словаря.